# Items to Invoice Section Collection in New Invoice Page

Tags: magento2

[image]

How can I apply Filter on this collection?
According to my Knowledge these rows are coming from `sales_order_item` so, I have custom attribute("admin_id") in `sales_order_item` . How can I apply condition on this collection?
Which **`class->method()`** is responsible for collecting this collection ?